# a variant of history.pushstate() javascript in php or jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this piece of javascript which gives me the opportunity to change the displayed url. The problem is that if I refresh after going to a page it doesn't find the page because the url has changed. Which makes alot of sense because javascript is client side. (see code below)

```
history.pushState("", "", "example");
```

I would like to know if this can be done server sided instead of client sided like with PHP or jQuery for instance?